# Azure Active Directory Authentication - 500 Error on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application that is authenticating against Azure AD. Everything authenticates when I run it locally from VS, but when I deploy the app to Azure, I get a 500 error: [myappname].azurewebsites.net is currently unable to handle this request. This is my configuration in my startup.cs file.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));
```

I have the redirect URIs setup in Azure as https://[my-appname].azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc as well as the localhost. I am not sure what I am missing.

UPDATE:
I setup the logs within Azure and this is what the 500 error is. Any ideas what might be happening?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 means internal error. There was an unhandled exception some where in your code.

When I get this problem I set up Application Insights and watch the log stream, to see what is actually failing.

See: https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip30.html

Comment: Wouldn't I see an internal error when I run locally?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this had nothing to do with Azure Active Directory. It was an issue with accessing the SQL database and I resolved it by adding permissions within the SQL server to allow my application access to the SQL database. This post helped me to figure this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/8602/msdn-redirect-publishing-aspnet-web-api-to-azure-a.html